# Symfony 2 - Validate a field with NotBlank & Type constraints

Tags: symfony

I am having problems validating a form component when i have added both NotBlank and Type validation to an integer field.

My validation.yml looks like the following:

```
Acme\StoreBundle\Entity\Foo:
properties:
    bar:
        - NotBlank: 
              message: You must specify a bar
        - Type:
             type: integer
             message: bar must be an integer
```

My FormType file looks like the following:

```
$builder->add('bar', 'integer', array(
            'label' => bar', 
            'error_bubbling' => true
));
```

When I type 'abc' into the field and submit, validate the form and getErrors(), the errors reported are -

```
This value is not valid.
You must specify a bar.
```

any ideas whats going wrong? I'm running Symfony 2.0.10

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. In the end, I used a normal 'text' field, and made my own 'Integer' validator which uses regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but maybe this helps:

```
$builder->add('bar', 'integer', array(
        'label' => bar',
        'invalid_message' => 'bar must be an integer'
        'error_bubbling' => true
));
```

Check [this](http://fatvegan.com/2011/12/21/symfony2-invalid-type-messages/) out

Comment: This kind of got me one step further, however i now see both 'bar must be an integer' and 'You must specify a bar', also, I dont see why I'd need to add an invalid message to the form component aswell as validation (basically duplicating code)?!

Comment: I don't know either. Maybe you can put empty invalid message to the form component such as `'invalid_message' => ' '`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be related to [this](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/2945) issue. From the discussion of the issue it seems that the solution of the problem is replacing [line 40 of the DelegatingValidator.php](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Validator/Validator/DelegatingValidator.php#L40) with this code

```
    if ($form->isRoot() && $form->isSynchronized()) {
```

I haven't tested it though. You can try and tell about the result :).

Comment: I've added this line as suggested and this doesnt seem to help, i still have the same problems :-(

Comment: Well I have tested it. Doesn't work indeed. Validation is done at [this](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Validator/Validator/DelegatingValidator.php#L80) line for top most form root which is synchronized. On second thought I think you don't have to set the field type as `integer`. As you have already added `integer` type validation constraint.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty late but this can help

- validation.yml

contactNo:

```
        - NotBlank: ~ 
        - Regex:
            pattern: '/\d/'
            match:   true
            message: Your contact no. must be a number                
        - Length: 
            min: 10
            max: 15
            minMessage: 'You contact no. must be at least {{ limit }} digits.'
            maxMessage: 'You contact no. can not be greater than {{ limit }} digits.'
```